# How to add a Vuetify only on the admin page ('admin/***')?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Now this library is connected globally
[image]

I tried to add it in the admin layout, but this method did not work.

[image]

Can I add it only on those pages that start with "/admin"?

Comment: Hey, don't post code images only on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `module` will be available globally, a `buildModule` will be compiled at build time and available globally too.

You will need several things to maybe make it work:

- use the old syntax like `import Vuetify from ...`
- add it to the `layouts/admin.vue` file only
- add the related CSS style there too (not sure if the CSS is tree-shakable there)

Meanwhile, since you do plan probably plan to have an admin dashboard separated from the main app, I think the best idea is to split the apps directly and maybe manage it through API calls or a headless CMS. But so far, I'm not sure that there is an easy solution here.

Comment: I don't want to separate it, because if the user is authorized, then the page will have interactive buttons for editing the content. And if the user is not logged in, then he should see a regular page.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, CSS is not that easy to lazy-load on demand. Also, here you're basically looking to load it if the end user have permission for it? IMO you should design your app in a way that the admin dashboard is either redirecting un-authorized somewhere else or use Vuetify for the whole app. You should meanwhile probably succeed to lazy-load the JS tied to Vuetify (I think). @ЕвгенийШевцов What is your use case to not wanting to split the admin path here? Do usual un-authorized users need the `admin` path so often? If not, you should probably not make it too complex at first.